# unbalance data random forest and other model used

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cross-validation

I have 100k unbalanced data at 98:2 ratio (binary classification).
I tried to extract that 98% class randomly and balance it up with the other class resulting in less than 3k data points.

My random forest AUC ROC achieved around 92%.

(I would not like to use SMOTE/oversampling/weighting the minority class as it makes results hard to interpret)

its a credit data btw. My fear is that it leads to extreme bias (random forest+ultra small sample)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: downsampling overrepresented class does not inhibit interpretation and is likely to increase AUC performance slightly. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/r-package-for-weighted-random-forest-classwt-option/158030#158030